# Download file by Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i search google and got a code snippet for downloading file by jquery. the syntax is like below

```
var downloadURL = function(url)
{
    var iframe;
    iframe = document.getElementById("hiddenDownloader");
    if (iframe === null)
    {
        iframe = document.createElement('iframe');  
        iframe.id = "hiddenDownloader";
        iframe.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    }
    iframe.src = url;   
}
```

but could not understand how it works. how call it and how to pass url. so please help me to use the above function and tell me how to pass url as argument. please also tell me what type of code is the above it is not a function.

```
var downloadURL = function(url)
```

how it works. variable name equal to function name. a function can be called but the above code snippet can not be called. so please discuss in detail. thanks.

Comment: `the above it is not a function` - in fact it is: the code is wrapped inside that `function(url)` at the top.

Comment: Simply call the function `downloadURL('your-url-here')`. That is basic JavaScript. I recommend to read a tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Comment: As far as I can tell, it isn't downloading anything, as much as storing the page's contents in a URL. And that is a function. You can call downloadURL('http://foo.com/bar.txt');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample code is an equivalent to doing this:

```
function downloadURL(url)
{
  var iframe;
  iframe = document.getElementById("hiddenDownloader");
  if (iframe === null)
  {
    iframe = document.createElement('iframe');  
    iframe.id = "hiddenDownloader";
    iframe.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  }
  iframe.src = url;   
}
```

Therefore you can call the function this way:

```
downloadURL('file.txt');
```

Now, what the function is doing is creating an iframe element in the page and setting the address to the url passed as argument, this will make the browser to show the download dialog for that file.

Hope this makes it clear.

Comment: This answer worked perfectly for my needs. Two small tidbits though: 1) I would change or add `iframe.style.display = 'none';` to the iframe. Setting the visibility will hide it but it still takes up room on the page as if it were there. [W3Schools link about visibility vs display.](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp). 2) Don't waste a ton of time testing this on an iPhone app (phonegap in my case) as iPhone doesn't like downloading files... I wasted many good hours this week already...

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is an interesting language and this is a quite valid way to define a function not the most prefereable in my opinion but usable.

To call this function all you have to do is this

```
downloadURL("http://a-url.com");
```

In javascript functions are just another type of object

Which makes it quite easy to pass functions to other functions as callbacks or create and call functions inline! A few examples!

```
function aFunc(callback){
 callback();
}

aFunc(function(){
  alert("Hi");
});
```

Thats a very simple example of a callback or as below inline functions

```
function aFunc(){
  (function(someVar){
    alert(someVar);
  })("Hi");
}
```

just another simple example of where functions don't have to be defined like you may have seen before

Comment: Functions are objects even in a strict sense ;)